# Cucumber adding # encoding: iso-8859-1 to feature file not working

Tags: java, cucumber

I am trying to change the encoding on my feature file so that it takes in account accents (like 'réunion').
So i have added the `#encoding: iso-8859-1` tag on top of my feature file :

```
# encoding: iso-8859-1
# language: fr

Fonctionnalité: Pouvoir lister les installations

Scénario: Demander la liste des installations
 Quand nous demandons la liste des installations
 Alors nous recevons les installations 'réunion'
```

But i got the following error :

> io.cucumber.core.gherkin.FeatureParserException: Failed to parse resource at: classpath:integration/installation.feature
> (4:1): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Fonctionnalité: Pouvoir lister les installations'
> (6:2): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Scénario: Demander la liste des installations'
> (7:4): expected: #TagLine, #FeatureLine, #Comment, #Empty, got 'Quand nous demandons la liste des installations'

If i don't add the encoding tag the accents are restitued like this : `R�union` instead of `Réunion` in my assertion test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your feature file is encoded with `UTF-8` or something else but not `iso-8859-1`.

**Convert your gherkin file to `iso-8859-1` encoding** and see if it still working.

Most software source code is encoded with UTF-8. You will not have problems with French characters in `UTF-8` encoded gherkin file.

```
# language: fr

Fonctionnalité: Pouvoir lister les installations
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi thx for your time.
I am not sure how i am supposed to convert my gherkin file to iso-8859-1 encoding without adding the # encoding: iso-8859-1 tag on top of my file.

Comment: `# encoding: iso-8859-1 tag` does not set encoding for a file. It is just a tag for `Cucumber`. Your IDE may have some features to change encoding like `File > File Properties`.

Comment: Indeed, now it works.